# Como faço para deixar essa matriz zerada na frente dos F's?

Tags: array, c++

Não consigo deixar a matriz zerada na frente dos F's. ela só fica atrás.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Utilize tabulação horizontal ('\t') e quebra de linha ('\n') para formatar sua linha. Ex.: `cout << "\nF" << (l+1) << " \t";` e `cout << poltronas[l][c] << "\t";`. Postar imagens não é uma atitude bem vinda neste site. Faça um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e entenda o porquê.

Answer (score 1):

Você está colocando um endl apos o 'F', ele vai quebrar a linha e ficar a frente dos espaços da linha anterior.

Tente isso:

```
for(int i = 0; i<18; i++){
    cout<<'F'<<(i+1);
    for(int j = 0; j<4; j++){
      cout<<poltona[i][j];
      if(j==3)
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.